# api item has image name but not url

Tags: javascript, php, image, api, url

it's probably a basic question but it seems i can't find a solution about this. 
It's my first time dealing with third party API, whose methods i'm restructuring in a personal php api service. 
All data are retrieved fine, but what i don't get is how to use the image if the content i'm getting is just:

```
{image: 'name-of-image.jpg'}
```

should i upload all the images i get from the call to the server? Shouldn't they be already allocated in a url? How do I do this... I'm lost. 
Thank you

Comment: Can you specify the purpose/functionality of the API?

Comment: @VedantBang it permits the access to customer data through a plain API, getting the customer car stock list

Comment: We can only guess as VendantBang said. It could also be the request path+ "/name-of-image.jpg"

Comment: @Leschge i tried it but the request address is not found

Comment: are there any documentation for the api you are using?... you could probably find where those images are found in

Comment: @Zirc in the documentation there wasn't any specific about this. My dumb error was not to inspect the path in which the image are allocated in the online website which i am restyling. Thank you all